# jQuery masonry how to call layoutComplete

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-masonry

I have the following function:

```
namespace.utils.pageReorder(feed, function() {
     console.log('complete');
     // do some stuff here no reorder has completed
});

-------------

pageReorder: function(feed, callback) {

    feed.masonry('reloadItems');
    feed.masonry('layout');

    callback();

},
```

What i need to be able to do is to only call the callback once the masonry layout has completed. I know masonry has the following method but im not sure how to integrate it into my function.

```
msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function() {
  console.log('layout is complete, just once');
  return true;
});
```

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 2):

```
pageReorder: function(feed, callback) {

    feed.masonry('reloadItems');
    feed.masonry('layout');

    feed.on( 'layoutComplete', function() {
       callback();
    });
},
```

This should work, by experience the layoutComplete of masonry cannot always be trusted.

Comment: layoutComplete does fail a lot. Wonder if you know any ways around this ?

Answer (score 2):

I found it working most reliable when registering the event listener before layouting.

Assuming feed is a jquery element:

```
feed.masonry({
  isInitLayout: false,
  transitionDuration: 0,});
var msnry = feed.data('masonry');

msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function() {
  console.log('layout is complete, just once');
});
msnry.layout();
```